# Push is not function Angularjs error

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.post1 = angular.fromJson(window.localStorage['like'] || '{}');

  var like ={
    id:''+id
  };
  $scope.post1.push(like);

window.localStorage['like'] = angular.toJson( $scope.post1);
```

When I run this code it gives **$scope.post1.push is not a function.**.How to solve this problem?

Comment: check the return type of `window.localstorage`. that should give you some clues. Use `angular.isArray(window.localstorage['like']);`

Comment: Object doesn't have push method, only array does.

Comment: In case post1 not being an array isn´t the problem you could try to put a $timeout after reading from local storage. It could be a matter of race conditions.      $timeout(function(){$scope.post1.push(like);},200);

Answer (score 1):

There is no push() function in javascript Object or String. But Array has it.

Maybe you could do something like this instead:

```
$scope.post1.like = { id: '' + id };
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson for more information about `angular.fromJson()` return type.

**Edit:**

It seems like I misread something. Try this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PXNul5c9FbKNHxhQZjEF

If you want to create array of object, you should pass array to angular.fromJson()

Comment: i want to make array of objects

Comment: simple,make post1 an array and push objects in it.